What determines which analysts get to be on an earnings call?
Example transcript from Starbucks
This earnings call had 10 analysts, representing institutions such as BofA, Morgan Stanley, Barclays, etc.
Question: why these 10 analysts? I'm sure there are more than 10 institutions in the world. What determines why these analysts get to join the call, while others don't?

Invitation from the call's host. And yes, that may imply selection bias, though a large number of trusted names is supposed to imply that there is at least some consensus.
If you don't trust that, find your own additional information sources. Criticism is not the purpose of the call; promotion is.

Worth noting that the analysts being invited (for large companies like in the question) are the ones covering the company. Think of the White House briefing - who gets invited?
